# Docusign USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP Issue

Tags: docusignapi

I am doing a couple of api calls “GET RecipientTabs”  and “DELETE Recipients” in my production environment and using sender of envelope as SOBO functionality in authentication header. We closed a user after he sent an envelope and envelope’s s status is in-process now. If I perform api calls on this envelope, I’m getting the following error:

> "errorCode": "USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP",
>
> "message": "The UserID does not have a valid membership in this Account."

As of my understanding, this error is occurring because the sender of envelope is closed and he is inactive now.  I have the docusign administrator rights in my production account and Is there any way to skip the issue and perform the api calls successfully  on envelope?

Comment: Take off the SOBO portion of the headers on the delete call. Delete it as yourself, instead of the closed user.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I called the docusign support today and they said the same thing. If I have to remove the SOBO portion, I need to re-deploy the api code. I was actually wondering whether anyone knows any work-around other than this. Well, deleting the sobo portion seems like the only way.

Comment: It is the only way for this scenario

Comment: I also threw this info into an answer. If this information helped you, please mark it as Solved so others can use this information as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this, you must remove the `<SendOnBehalfOf></SendOnBehalfOf>` portion of your headers.

The request is attempting to make the call as a closed user, that user does not have access to make API calls or access anything else inside of DocuSign.

Making the call as the administrator will grant access to all envelopes under that account and be able to execute what you're attempting to execute.

Comment: If there is immediate requirement to complete the envelope, administrator can share the sender's envelope to himself and correct it manually through docusign web console. Of course, it would be cumbersome but works as temporary fix for one or two envelopes.